# Soccer league and team hierarchical metadata

Tags: data-request, sports, ontology

I'm looking for hierarchical metadata for soccer leagues and teams. I'm looking for any region or country (although Switzerland would be the first choice). There are many league or association website, but they don't have structured or machine readable data - and hence no real data model. So key is that the data is structured and machine readable (Wikidata like). No preference for API or database or files.

The hierarchy would be something like this:

```
Country/Region > Gender/Age group > League > Team > Team Details
```

If no structured and machine readable data exists for soccer, I'll accept for other sports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.org has some decent categories, split between "[Sports Organization](https://schema.org/SportsOrganization)" and "[Sports Team](https://schema.org/SportsTeam)". Also useful is "Sports Vocabulary" ([PDF](https://www.w3.org/wiki/images/8/87/Schema-sports-vocabulary-final_20120301.pdf)).

Another Q/A here, as a reference: [Schema.org - Correct way to set up a football (soccer) club with multiple teams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29052339/2327328)